# errors in gstreamer ios tutorials

Tags: ios, gstreamer

I downloaded gstreamer-1.0-devel-1.8.1-ios-universal-pkg and am trying to compile and run the `GStreamer` iOS Tutorials.  I get an

> implicit declaration of function get_registry_get_default is invalid
>   in C99

error in `gst_ios_init()` on line 1028.  If I have Xcode "fix" it, I then get

> Could not create compact unwind for _ffi_call_unix64: does not use RBP
>   or RSP based frame

and then a bunch of undefined symbols for architecture x86_64.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo there: It's not get_registry_get_default() but gst_registry_get_default(). That's what XCode is probably fixing for real there.

What are the other undefined symbols?

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_gst_plugin_mad_register", referenced from:
      _gst_ios_init in gst_ios_init.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)      in ios